# Finding image resource in iOS app (XCode 4.2)

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage

This feels like a silly question but I'm stumped. I working on an iOS app using XCode 4.2 and I can't find an image file anywhere in the project. The image filename is passed to `UIImage imageNamed:` so it has to be somewhere local (not downloading it from remote server). **What's the best way to find the image?**

In my own iOS projects it's trivially easy to locate images: look in the `Resources` group in the project directory. I've inherited this application and looking in Resources turns up nothing.

Comment: so where was the image located?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bottom of the navigation panel has an input field which filters what's displayed

[image]

Comment: That will filter/search all files in the project.

Answer (score 2):

Try the `Supporting Files` folder